# Thevenin Voltage with only Dependant Sources?

Tags: thevenin, linearity

If I have a circuit composed of only dependant sources with linear control functions (ie a voltage source with a voltage of bVx, where b is a constant and Vx is some other potential in the circuit) and linear resistors, won’t the Thevenin Voltage always be zero? The only solution seems to be for every voltage and current in the circuit to be zero. Wouldn’t anything else break linearity?

Comment: Without a schematic diagram, it is difficult to comment. Please post one.

Answer (score 0):

If a circuit doesn't have any inputs, Vth will be zero.

If you do the equivalent, you can only get the resistance as seen by one of the terminals using an external source and use Ohm's Law to find Rth viewed by that "new" source.

So, if there aren't any inputs, you get an equivalent circuit with Vth=0 and Rth=Req.